# angularjs move element/directive from one list to another without reinitialization

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, move

Lets image that we have two lists of elements, where each element itself is a directive.

```
List 1:
 - A 
 - B
 - C
List 2:
 - X
 - Y
 - Z
```

I want to move element "Y" from list 2 to list 1 *without reinitializing the directive*. Hence, I want to simply move the contents/directive from list 2 to list 1.

I made a simple example to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/24171/

As you can see from the example, the console prints 'init: Y' again, after moving the element. But I don't want that. I just want to have it moved.

How can I do this without reinitializing the directive?

---

template.html

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h2>List 1:</h2>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="entry in list1">
      <span my-directive="entry"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h2>List 2:</h2>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="entry in list2">
      <span my-directive="entry"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button ng-click="move()">
    Move 'Y' to List 1
  </button>
</div>
```

app.js

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        myDirective: '='
      },
      template: '{{myDirective}}',
      controller: function($scope) {
        console.log('init: ' + $scope.myDirective);
      }
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
    $scope.list2 = ['X', 'Y', 'Z'];

    $scope.move = function() {
      var entries = $scope.list2.splice(1,1);
      $scope.list1.push(entries[0]);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your directive is used inside and `ng-repeat`, every item addition will create a new scope and thus directive controller will be initialized every time. You can however do it the other way around, i.e. bind your list to the directive and have ng-repeat within the template. See the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehmorzpx/). Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: This does not work. You have to imagine that `my-directive` is a very complex and deep one. Hence, `entry` would still be initialized again (but one layer deeper). See [updated Fiddle of your version](http://jsfiddle.net/kk1L54wL/).

Comment: Your updated fiddle has a syntax error and doesn't run. Can you correct it and post again with the problem?